# INotifyDataErrorInfo. ErrorsChanged how to make wpf show the errors of property like `Address.Country`

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm, inotifydataerrorinfo

There is only 3 things inside of INotifyDataErrorInfo:

`HasErrors`: a read-only boolean property which tells if the object as a whole have any validation errors;
`GetErrors`: a method which returns validation errors for a given property;
`ErrorsChanged`: an event which must be raised when new errors – or the lacks of errors – is detected. You have to raise this event for each property.

---

In the demo project I create a form which display the properties of an object named `‘Person’`. Here is how the validation with INotifyDataErrorInfo is enabled in the Binding:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay,ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}"/>
```

We have to set the `ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors` property to `true`.

**The binding will then register itself for the ErrorsChanged event of the binded Person. Eeach time this event is raised for the binded property, the controls will dress itself to display an error. this is done only if the HasErrors is set to true.**

---

Question:

1. Is there anyone know more detail aobut the `ErrorsChanged event is raised for
       the binded property, the controls will dress itself to display an
       error`?
2. If I binding `Address.Country` of `Person` ,will the `ErrorsChanged` event be raised for the  binded property `Address.Country` or not? why? is there a way make this binding to show Errors too?

   `<TextBox Text="{Binding Address.Country,Mode=TwoWay,ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}"/>`

Answer (score 4):

I think I can risk an answer, this question is already one year old.

The Binding will register to the `ErrorsChanged` event in the Class containing the property. In that case, Address must implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo`.

And, it's you to raise the `ErrorsChanged` event when you implement the validation logic. Once you have validated the Address.Country, you store the ValidationResults (or simple strings list) and raise the event. The Binding will get the stored ValidationResults list for the PropertyName he is binded to, by calling the method `GetErrors(string propertyName)`that you wrote yourself implementing the INotifyDataErrorInfo interface.

If this list is not empty, the Binding will set the Property `Validation.HasError` to True and the control will raise the `Validation.Error` event. Some controls have a built-in behavior to change their appearance in error case (a TextBox will have a red frame around its border). If you want to show the errors, you have to retrieve them by writing a style in xaml. Plenty of examples out there.

The `HasErrors` method is used if you want to know if the Person has any errors in its Properties. It's mostly used in such cases : enabling or disabling a save button. Once again, it's you to implement the logic using the `HasErrors` Property. It's mostly done by binding it to a control Property in xaml.